# How to Add 4 Blank Columns to a pipe delimited CSV via Command Line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, pipe, delimiter

I am on a Windows machine.

I have a CSV file that looks like below that use pipe as the delimiter:

```
Column 1 | Column 2  | Column 3
1 | 2 | 3
1 | 2 | 3
```

And I need to add 4 blank columns to make it look like:

```
Column 1 | Column 2  | Column 3 ||||
1 | 2 | 3 ||||
1 | 2 | 3 ||||
```

This works fine if my delimiter was a CSV, but can't figure out what to do for the pipe.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "Test.csv"') do (
 >>"fileout.csv" echo.%%a,,,,
 )
```

My expected output is as follows

```
Column 1 | Column 2  | Column 3 ||||    
1 | 2 | 3 ||||    
1 | 2 | 3 ||||
```

Comment: escape the pipe characters `|` with a caret `^` i.e `^|` also, rather use `echo(` than `echo.` in otherwords just change to `echo(%%a^|^|^|^|`

Comment: There is no need to use the `TYPE` command.  You actually slow down the processing on larger files.  The performance hit is quite significant on larger files. `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("Test.csv") do`

Answer (score 0):

The escape character for batch scripts is the caret - you can use your existing code, just add a caret before each pipe:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "Test.csv"') do (
    >>"fileout.csv" echo.%%a^|^|^|^|
)
```